# Generating a row from rows with a trigger

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-trigger

I'm working on a trigger to create a new row in one table based on data from multiple rows in another one.

Basically I get a bunch of rows in at once and a few of those have information about users that I need to get into the table "nemendur" (students).

I've gone back and forth and on this but I keep getting a whole lot of errors, including ifs, inserts and updates. Seems the only thing that's working properly is setting the @info value.

Table nemendur:

```
ID           int PK AI not null 
nafn         varchar not null   (name of student)
email        varchar            (email of student)
kennitala    varchar            (SSN)
post_id      int unique
```

Table uppl (short for upplýsingar or information):

```
meta_id      int AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL     
post_id      int
meta_key     varchar
meta_value   TEXT
```

This table is generated automaticcally by the wordpress database. 
I get information from a form I created into this table where the fields on the form have a "meta_key" value of either "nem_nafn", "nem_email" or "nem_kennitala".

I need these information in the table above where the "meta_value" is inserted in the fields corresponding to the "meta_key"(s) in this one.

I think this is a pretty straight forward code, but please if it's not clear enough, let me know so I can try to explain it better.

Oh, and the information I need is always in this order: name > email > SSN. It's relevant as to how this code could work (if the name appears last the other two would have no row to be updated to).

```
drop trigger if exists p;
delimiter $$
create trigger p
AFTER INSERT ON uppl 
FOR EACH ROW

begin

SET @info = 
(
    SELECT meta_value
    WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_name'
);

IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

    INSERT INTO nemendur(id, nafn, email, kennitala, post_id)
    VALUES
    ('', @info, '', '', NEW.post_id);
ELSE
    SET @info = 
    (SELECT meta_value
    WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_email');

    IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

        UPDATE nemendur
        SET email = @info
        WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;

    ELSE

        SET @info = (SELECT meta_value
                WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_kennitala');

        if @info IS NOT NULL THEN

            UPDATE nemendur
            SET kennitala = @info
            WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;

end $$
delimiter $$
```

Summary: a bunch of lines go in the "uppl" table, but only if one with a relevant "meta_key" enters the table the "meta_value" is put in the "nemendur" table.

All errors I get are #1064, "Check the manual that corresponds with your NariaDB server version for the right syntax". At this time it says at line 7, i.e. the "IF" statement.

Thanks in advance,
WeirdGuy

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sloan, wasn't sure how to fix that ;)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the errors are? You do need to explain in more detail what the code is supposed to do. Include table schemas, expected results, etc.

Comment: Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Do you have a UNIQUE KEY defined for `nemendur.post_id`? If so, you could do this with one statement using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: Could you clarify? I don't see how I could do that. Correct me if I'm wrong but I could change the "updates" sure but that's not really the problem since I know the row is there if the code runs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have brackets where you don't need them, missing brackets where you should have them and you are missing a wedge of end ifs.

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
SET @info = 
(
    SELECT meta_value
    WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_name'
);

IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

    INSERT INTO nemendur(id, nafn, email, kennitala, post_id)
    VALUES
    ('', @info, '', '', NEW.post_id);
ELSE
    SET @info = 
    (SELECT meta_value
    WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_email');

    IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

        UPDATE nemendur
        SET email = @info
        WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;

    ELSE

        SET @info = (SELECT meta_value
                WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_kennitala');

        if @info IS NOT NULL THEN

            UPDATE nemendur
            SET kennitala = @info
            WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;
       end if;
   end if;
end if;

end $$
delimiter $$
```

Note I know this is a procedure...

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Still getting that syntax error on line 7 thou, any idea what that might be?

Comment: I don't - are you sure you copied the whole thing delimiters included.

Comment: Just ran the whole thing, apparently this code works for a procedure but if I change it to a trigger then it all goes south :/. I'll get back in a few after I try a few things :)

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to include the full trigger (create etc..)

Comment: About to update, got it to run without errors but now it drops the trigger if it exists, but it doesn't create it.